# setTimeout runs immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have some elements on my page, i want to call a function over them by JQuery extended function. I have this function declarement:

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.enable = function (delay) {
            console.log(delay); //logs 3000
            setTimeout(function (elem) {
                console.log(elem);
                elem.css("opacity", "1");
            }(this), delay);
            return this;
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

as you know, which declares a `enable` function over JQuery objects. now when i call something like this:

```
$("#start").enable(3000);
```

the function `enable` runs, but the code inside `function (elem)...` runs immediately instead of running after a while!

**How and Why??**

Comment: If you end your anonymous function with `(this)` you're passing in it's return value, not the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are calling  the function "function(elem)" instead of providing it as an arguement. Try this

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.enable = function (delay) {
            console.log(delay); //logs 3000
             var elem = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(elem);
                elem.css("opacity", "1");
            }, delay);  //you should not call a function here
            return this;
        };
    })(jQuery);
```